# Min Binary Heap issue

Tags: c++, algorithm, heap, binary-heap

i need help with this minheap code:

```
#include < vector>

using namespace std;

class heap {

    vector <int> v;

    public:

        int hSize()
        {
            return v.size();
        }

        int rsize()
        {
            return  hSize() - 1;
        }    

        int parent(int i) 
        {
            return (i - 1) / 2;
        }

        int left(int i)
        {
            return i * 2 + 1;
        }

        int right(int i)
        {
            return i * 2 + 2;
        }

        void swap(int i, int j)
        {
            int temp = v[j];
            v[j] = v[i];
            v[i] = temp;
        }

        void push(int e)
        {

            v.push_back(e);
            int id = rsize(); 

            if (hSize() > 1)
                while (v[parent(id)] > v[id]) {               
                    swap(parent(id), id);
                    id = parent(id);
                }
        }

        int pop ()
        {

          int f = 0;  
          int p = v[0];

          v[0] = v[rsize()];

          if (hSize() > 1) {
              while (v[left(f)] < v[f] || v[right(f)] < v[f]) {
                    if (v[left(f)] < v[f] && v[right(f)] < v[f]) {
                        if (v[left(f)] < v[right(f)]) {
                            swap(left(f), f);
                            f = left(f);
                    }
                    else { 
                            swap(right(f), f);
                            f = right(f);
                    }
                }

                else {
                    if (v[left(f)] < v[f]){
                         swap(left(f), f);
                         f = left(f);
                    }
                    else {
                         swap(right(f), f);
                         f = right(f);
                        }
                    }
                } 
          }
          else { }

          v.resize(rsize());
          return p;
        }

        void show()
        {
            if (hSize() > 0) {
                cout << "Heap content: ";
                for (int i = 0; i < hSize(); i++) cout << v[i] << " ";
            }
            else cout << "\nHeap successfully emptied!";  
            cout << "\n";          
        }

        bool Empty()
        {
            return v.empty();
        }

        ~heap()
        {
            v.clear();
        }

    };
```

Well, the code does almost everything right, except when it pops the last element on the screen it prints a random number. What's your opinion?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You can format a piece code by indenting 4 spaces or 1 tab.

Comment: Also, unless it's a homework, you should use a `priority_queue`. (http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/priority_queue.html).

Comment: well, besides wanting to understand it myself, i need a custom minheap for my pathfinding algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Debugging**

- You can run the code with valgrind to see if it reports any errors.
- You can run the code within a debugger (takes longer to debug but more likelihood of success).

**Coding**
You should use assertions. For example, the first line of the `swap` function can be `assert(i >= 0 && i < v.size());` and similarly for `j`. I suspect putting these two assertions in will tell you the errors. When you're done, if you like you can comment out the assertions (although some people like to leave some of the assertions on always).

**Update**
Your code was alright. Just needed to add the bounds check inside swap and return if not satisfied. Here is the code and the test case (which passed when I ran):

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class heap {

    vector <int> v;

    public:

        int hSize()
        {
            return v.size();
        }

        int rsize()
        {
            return  hSize() - 1;
        }

        int parent(int i)
        {
            return (i - 1) / 2;
        }

        int left(int i)
        {
            return i * 2 + 1;
        }

        int right(int i)
        {
            return i * 2 + 2;
        }

        void swap(int i, int j)
        {
            //assert(i >= 0 && i < v.size()); 
            //assert(j >= 0 && j < v.size()); 
            if(i >= v.size() || j >= v.size()) return;
            int temp = v[j];
           v[j] = v[i];
            v[i] = temp;
        }

        void push(int e)
        {

            v.push_back(e);
            int id = rsize();

            if (hSize() > 1)
                while (v[parent(id)] > v[id]) {
                    swap(parent(id), id);
                    id = parent(id);
                }
        }

        int pop ()
        {

          int f = 0;
          int p = v[0];

          v[0] = v[rsize()];

          if (hSize() > 1) {
                  while (v[left(f)] < v[f] || v[right(f)] < v[f]) {
                          if (v[left(f)] < v[f] && v[right(f)] < v[f]) {
                                  if (v[left(f)] < v[right(f)]) {
                                          swap(left(f), f);
                                          f = left(f);
                                  }
                                  else {
                                          swap(right(f), f);
                                          f = right(f);
                                  }
                          }

                          else {
                                  if (v[left(f)] < v[f]){
                                          swap(left(f), f);
                                          f = left(f);
                                  }
                                  else {                                         swap(right(f), f);
                                          f = right(f);
                                  }
                          }
                  }
          }
          else { }

          v.resize(rsize());
          return p;
        }

        void show()
        {
                if (hSize() > 0) {
                        cout << "Heap content: ";
                        for (int i = 0; i < hSize(); i++) cout << v[i] << " ";
                }
                else cout << "\nHeap successfully emptied!";
                cout << "\n";
        }

        bool Empty()
        {
                return v.empty();
        }

        ~heap()
        {
                v.clear();
        }

};


int main()
{
        heap h;
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        h.push(rand()%10);
        h.push(4);
        h.push(3);
        h.push(2);
        h.push(1);
        h.push(0);
        h.push(5);
        h.push(-6);
        h.push(7);
        h.show();
        h.pop();
        h.pop();
        h.pop();
        h.pop();
        h.pop();
        h.pop();
        h.pop();
        h.pop();
        h.pop();
        h.show();
        }
}
```

After putting the assertion in, I ran the code in the debugger to find that the crash occurred in the line `swap(right(f), f);` and `right(f)` was out of bounds.

Comment: well after putting those two it says "Assertion failed" and the program crashes, any idea why?

Comment: @vladdx I tried running the code but it works for me (no crash). Can you please add a test case or main() function in your question so I can reproduce the crash?

Comment: @vladdx You can otherwise try running the code (with the assertion in place) inside gdb debugger (if you are using linux; but for running on gdb you need to compile the code with "g++ -g3"). At the place it crashes, you can view the stack with "bt" command. You can traverse the stack with "up" and "down" commands, and print the value of a variable using "p <variable name>" command. So you can see if the value of `i` and `j` make sense.

Comment: Yes, it works now Amit, thanks a lot!

Now to code the pathfinding algorithm! :)

Answer (score 2):

You have two similar problems, one in `push()` and one in `pop()`.  In push you need to check that `id != 0` before looking at `v[parent(id)]`.  If `id == 0`you are at the root and you should halt.  Similarly, in `pop()` you should check if `right(f)` (or `left(f)`) is within the vector before accessing `v[right(f)]` (or `v[left(f)]`).  If it is not, you have reached the bottom of the heap and you should halt.

Comment: Well after doing what you said for i.e. 13, 5, 1, 3 ,17 prints 1, 3, -xxxxxxx, 5, 13 so another problem.

What do you think?